Sum of two big numbers returns a NaN value in Javascript
I was making a summation algorithm to add 2 very big numbers.


//input 
let n1 = 1234567891234556555558
let n2 = 1234567891234556555558

//processing
let a = n1.toString()
let b = n2.toString()
let c = 0  //carry
let r = ''  //final result of summation

for (let i = 1; i <= Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
    if(a.length == b.length) {
        let v = parseInt(a[a.length - i]) + parseInt(b[b.length - i]) + c; c = 0
        if(v.toString().length == 1) {
            r = v + r.slice(0, r.length)
        }
        else {
            r = parseInt(v.toString()[1]) + r.slice(0, r.length)
            c = parseInt(v.toString()[0])
        }
    }
}

//output
console.log(r)



The code works for small values but returns a NaN for big values.
I tried to change how the c is declared, I thought it might be still a string but the result is still the same.
Please note the algorithm only works for numbers of the same length.

You're exceeding the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER value. Use a BigInt type instead.

r = v + r.slice(0, r.length) you forgot to string on v here

check what a and b are ... hint, the third last character on them both are +

The problem starts in the first line. You can't store the input numbers as numbers: https://jsfiddle.net/c6htnyb4/ 1234567891234556555558 == 1234567891234556555557 returns true in JavaScript.

I'm assuming your doing this as a project, eg. adding up like a human with carry etc.   BigInt's are built into JavaScript these days, so a really simple fix for your algorithm is just put a lowercase n at the end of those 2 numbers, as toString() also works on BigInt and the rest of your code will work as expected..

@RoryMcCrossan Oh yeah tried it right now it did work. Thanks for the help.

@Keith Yes it worked. Thank you.

JavaScript's Number type can't handle very large integers accurately because of precision limits. To work with such large numbers, you should use strings and manually handle the addition of each digit.
Here's a working code:


    let n1 = "1234567891234556555558";
    let n2 = "1234567891234556555558";

    // processing
    let a = n1.toString();
    let b = n2.toString();
    let c = 0; // carry
    let r = ''; // final result of summation

    // Reverse the strings to make addition easier from the least significant digit
    a = a.split('').reverse().join('');
    b = b.split('').reverse().join('');

    // Loop through each digit
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
        let n1a = i < a.length ? parseInt(a[i]) : 0;
        let n2a = i < b.length ? parseInt(b[i]) : 0;

        let sum = n1a + n2a + c;
        c = Math.floor(sum / 10); // carry for next iteration
        r = (sum % 10) + r; // current digit result
    }

    // If there's a carry left at the end, add it to the result
    if (c > 0) {
        r = c + r;
    }

    console.log(`output : ${r}`); // Output the result
    alert(`output : ${r}`);




What is: let a = n1.toString(); let b = n2.toString(); supposed to do?

@MikeB let a = n1.toString(); and let b = n2.toString(); are used to convert the variables n1 and n2 into string format

@AkshayKumar right, but they are strings. Why would you convert the string to a string?

That split/reverse/join is going to be expensive for large numbers. Probably better just to  use  i--  in your loop to count downwards.

Yes,  You're correct that using split, reverse, and join can be less efficient, especially for large numbers. A more direct approach, like counting downwards with i--, can indeed be more efficient. @MikeB
